# Should I keep order history on Woocommerce? GDPR

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm currently going through the process of making sure my Woocommerce websites are compliant with the GDPR legislation coming into effect, May 25th. The default way Woocommerce works is that it stores every order in the database so customers are able to view their previous orders and the admins can process them.

My question is.. Should I introduce a way customers can delete their own orders? Or a maximum amount of time I hold onto these before automatically deleting?

Is there an industry standard for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.shopify.com/blog/gdpr-and-ecommerce

Comment: Remember that this kind of question is just off-topic on stackOverFlow as it's not directly related to coding, and could be closed by moderators…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at is the right for no longer relevant data to be erased. Keep in mind this is different from the right to be forgotten. This does not need to be a programatic thing. Sites like Facebook and Google give a set of admin controls to do this so they don't need to process hundreds of thousands of users individually. The rules state 30 days from request.

A note in site terms on an email to contact to have your data deleted really should suffice. Again keep in mind it is legal to keep sales data, only specific data may be requested to be destroyed. This is paramount in an e-commerce environment.

There are WP plugins to allow users to delete their account but this may cause issues with WC.

A good place to start is with WooCommerces own blog post on the issue
https://woocommerce.com/2017/12/gdpr-compliance-woocommerce/

For full detail of the right of erasure check here
https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-to-erasure/

Comment: Perfect, just the answer I was hoping for :) Thank you